# Terraform Windows server 2016 adding and running scripts using winery

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, windows-server-2016, winrm

I'm of a need to add one powershell script into a windows server 2016 and run in after to install a specific program.

The code that I'm using will be shared only for the Windows Machine creation since the rest of it is only default settings.

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm-clt" {
  count = local.VMInstance
  name                        = "windows${count.index + 1}"
  location                    = var.location
  availability_set_id         = azurerm_availability_set.avset.id
  resource_group_name         = var.resource_group_name
  network_interface_ids       = [element(azurerm_network_interface.nic_vm.*.id, count.index)]
  size                        = "Standard_B1s"
  admin_username              = var.username
  admin_password              = var.adminpassword
  enable_automatic_updates    = "false"
  provision_vm_agent          = "true"
  depends_on                  = [azurerm_network_interface.nic_vm]

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_disk {
    name              = lower("${local.prefixStorageName}${count.index + 1}")
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type  = "Premium_LRS"
  }
provisioner "file" {
  source      = "Agent.ps1"
  destination = "C:/Windows/Temp/Agent.ps1"

  connection {
    type     = "winrm"
    port = "5985"
    https = false
    insecure = true 
    user     = var.username
    password = var.adminpassword
    host     = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.pip_vm.*.ip_address, count.index)}"
    timeout  = "5m" 
  }
}

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
inline = [         
           "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\\Windows\\Temp\\Agent.ps1  -APIKey 2b076e91c7xxxxxxxx4fd25a094dce"
     ]
    connection {
      type     = "winrm"
      user     = var.username
      password = var.adminpassword
      host     = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.pip_vm.*.ip_address, count.index)}"
      timeout  = "5m" 
    }
  }
}
```

the error that I receive while deploying is: timeout - last error: unknown error Post "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5985/wsman": dial tcp XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5985: i/o timeout

**NOTE**: the error is only available during terraform apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some configuration in `azurerm_windows_virtual_machine` like `winrm_listner` and `additional_unattend_content`. Also not sure if you have added NSG for `WinRm` port.

So, after doing some changes , I tested with below script :

```
provider "azurerm"{
  features{}
}

variable "admin_username" {
    type = string
    default = "adminuser"
}

variable "admin_password" {
    type = string
    default = "Paassworrdd@12344"
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "ansumantest"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "windows_pip" {
  name                = "examplevm-PIP"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "windows_nsg" {
  name                = "exampleVM-NSG"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "RDP"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "3389"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "WinRM"
    priority                   = 110
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "5985"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "HTTP"
    priority                   = 120
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "80"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.windows_nsg.id
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.windows_pip.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm_persistent" {
  name                = "vm-persistent"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_D4_v3"

# Here my variables for User/Password
  admin_username      = var.admin_username
  admin_password      = var.admin_password
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.example.id]
  custom_data = "${filebase64("C:/Users/user/terraform/test/winrm.ps1")}"
  provision_vm_agent = "true" 
  winrm_listener {
      protocol = "Http" 
  }
  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  additional_unattend_content {
      setting      = "AutoLogon"
      content      = "<AutoLogon><Password><Value>${var.admin_password}</Value></Password><Enabled>true</Enabled><LogonCount>1</LogonCount><Username>${var.admin_username}</Username></AutoLogon>"
  }
  additional_unattend_content {
      setting      = "FirstLogonCommands"
      content      = "${file("C:/Users/user/terraform/test/firstlogincommand.xml")}"
  }
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      host     = azurerm_public_ip.windows_pip.ip_address
      type     = "winrm"
      port     = 5985
      https    = false
      timeout  = "5m"
      user     = var.admin_username
      password = var.admin_password
    }
    inline = [
      "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command {Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools}",
    ]
}
}
```

**FirstLogincommand.xml file**

```
<FirstLogonCommands>
    <SynchronousCommand>
        <CommandLine>cmd /c "copy C:\AzureData\CustomData.bin C:\winrm.ps1"</CommandLine>
        <Description>Move the CustomData file to the working directory</Description>
        <Order>12</Order>
    </SynchronousCommand>
    <SynchronousCommand>
        <CommandLine>powershell.exe -sta -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file C:\winrm.ps1</CommandLine>
        <Description>Execute the WinRM enabling script</Description>
        <Order>13</Order>
    </SynchronousCommand>
</FirstLogonCommands>
```

**winrm.ps1**

```
Write-Host "Delete any existing WinRM listeners"
winrm delete winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP  2>$Null
winrm delete winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS 2>$Null

Write-Host "Create a new WinRM listener and configure"
winrm create winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="0"}'
winrm set winrm/config '@{MaxTimeoutms="7200000"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser="12000"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/client/auth '@{Basic="true"}'

Write-Host "Configure UAC to allow privilege elevation in remote shells"
$Key = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System'
$Setting = 'LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $Key -Name $Setting -Value 1 -Force

Write-Host "turn off PowerShell execution policy restrictions"
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Write-Host "Configure and restart the WinRM Service; Enable the required firewall exception"
Stop-Service -Name WinRM
Set-Service -Name WinRM -StartupType Automatic
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" new action=allow localip=any remoteip=any
Start-Service -Name WinRM
```

**Output:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @AnsumanBal-MT I had other issues that needed to be resolved that's why I was not able to respond faster. The solution works and I can execute powershell scripts

Comment: Np @Igor,glad to be of help!!